# Visual Studio using Docker Desktop from another PC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, docker-desktop

I want to use Visual Studio (not Visual Studio Code) with Docker/Docker Desktop but I want Docker to be on another machine. One reason is that I have VMware and does not work well when I use Docker.
So I have on my PC a Windows 10 host with:

- Visual Studio 2022 community
- VMware running another Windows 10 (guest), having:

  - Docker Desktop
  - Visual Studio 2022 community

In the guest OS, I have a Visual Studio solution and I can debug an application with Docker just fine so I know that Docker/Docker Desktop work there.

In the host OS, I also have a Visual Studio solution and I added in its Docker file the line

```
ENV DOCKER_HOST tcp://192.168.111.222:2375
```

hopping to make it work with the remote Docker. When I try to start debugging, VS gives me the error:

1>docker build -f "C:\Work\WebApp\MainProj\Dockerfile" --force-rm -t mainproj:dev --target base  --label "com.microsoft.created-by=visual-studio" --label "com.microsoft.visual-studio.project-name=MainProj" "C:\Work\WebApp"
1>ERROR: error during connect: in the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be run with elevated privileges to connect: Get "http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/_ping": open //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified.
1>C:\Users\john.nuget\packages\microsoft.visualstudio.azure.containers.tools.targets\1.18.1\build\Container.targets(213,5): error CTC1003: Visual Studio container tools require Docker to be running.

I mention that I start Visual Studio as administrator and that on guest I have disabled the firewall. The applications are Aspnet MVC Applications with dotnet core.

In the guest I have enabled Windows Features: Containers, Hyper-V, Virtual Machine Platform, Windows Subsystem For Linux. I have run there:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype auto
```

In the host I have enabled Wondows Features: Containers, Hyper-V, Windows Subsystem For Linux. I have run there:

```
bcdedit /set hypervisorlaunchtype off
```